# onChange Checkbox Highlight Row

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, checkbox

I'm trying to use a script that I thought would be incredibly useful but I must not be getting it. All it is is a simple check the box, highlight the row kind of script but I'm getting stuck somewhere.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("input[type='checkbox']").on('change', function() {
    if ($(this).is(":checked")) {
      $(this).closest('tr').addClass("highlight");

    } else {
      $(this).closest('tr').removeClass("highlight");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
.highlight {
  background-color: red
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<table>
  <tr>
    <td><input id="checkboxSelect" type="checkbox"></td>
    <td>231540</td>
    <td>2018-02-25 00:00:00</td>
    <td>93.50</td>
  </tr>
  <table>
```

So when the checkbox of that particular row is checked I want to be able to add the class "highlight" to that checkbox's table row.

UPDATED //

I have also tried one of the suggested answers with the following script:

```
$("#checkboxSelect").click(function(){
if ($(this).is(":checked")){
 $(this).parent().parent().removeClass("highlight");
 alert('hello');}
else{
$(this).parent().parent().addClass("highlight");
alert('goodbye');}
    });
```

It still won't fire, I have tested it on jsFiddle and it does work there, but in my environment it just won't fire.

In case it means anything this is technically how these rows are generated:

```
$.ajax({
            type:'GET',
            url: '/customers/details/openInvoices',
            dataType:'json',
            data: {
                'customerID': $('select[name=payer_id]').val(),
               '_token': $('input[name=_token]').val(),
            },
                success: function(data) {
                    $('.errorTitle').addClass('hidden');
                    $('.errorContent').addClass('hidden');

                    if ((data.errors)) {
                        setTimeout(function () {
                            $('#createOrigin').modal('show');
                            toastr.error('Check your inputs!', 'Error Alert', {timeOut: 5000});
                        }, 500);

                        if (data.errors.title) {
                            $('.errorTitle').removeClass('hidden');
                            $('.errorTitle').text(data.errors.title);
                        }
                        if (data.errors.content) {
                            $('.errorContent').removeClass('hidden');
                            $('.errorContent').text(data.errors.content);
                        }
                    } else {
                         $.each(data, function(i,val) {
                                    $('<tr>').append(
                                    $('<td>').html('<input type="checkbox" class="checkboxSelect">'),
                                    $('<td>').text(val.pro_number),
                                    $('<td>').text(val.due_date),
                                    $('<td>').text(val.balance)).appendTo('#customerOpenInvoicesTable');
                            $('#openInvoicesOverlay').html('');
                             $('#openInvoicesOverlay').removeClass('overlay');

               });
              }
             }
            });
```

Comment: this seems to be correct already

Comment: I have create a snippet based on your code and its working. Can you reproduce the issue?

Comment: Everything is exactly the same :/ I've even added your choice for obvious styling the rows. But the row class just isn't added. Do you have any suggestions for maybe achieving this through in alternative? Maybe a reference to the onChange event function directly on the checkbox?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use jquery..

And don't forget to add jquery cdn......

```
$("#checkboxSelect").click(function(){
if ($(this).is(":checked")){
 $(this).parent().parent().removeClass("highlight")}
else{
$(this).parent().parent().addClass("highlight")}
    });
```

That will do it...

Comment: Alright, I've tried yours and it still won't fire. I've added two semicolons where they were supposed to be but I believe it's something to do with not recognizing the checkboxes. See my edits to my question.